# Converter Html em texto legível usando MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um texto no banco de dados desta forma: Exemplo apenas:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>&nbsp;asdsdasdadsdadsa <em>asdsd asdsdasdasdad</em></strong>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>asdas</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A informação está com as tags HTML, eu quero poder trazer esse texto e mostra de uma forma legível na página. Aonde desapareça essas tags e mostre apenas o texto.
Eu usei esse código:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {

            QuemSomos model = _repositorio.BuscarPorId(id);
            var quemSomosMapper = Mapper.Map<QuemSomos, QuemSomosViewModel>(model);

            ViewBag.conversao = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(quemSomosMapper.Texto.ToString());

            return View(ViewBag.conversao);
        }
```

Más não ta funcionando. Gostaria de uma ajuda se for possível.

Comment: Alysson, você quer remover as tags HTML ou interpretar o HTML na view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente as opções abaixo:

**1**

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

**2**

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Properties.Resources.HtmlContents);
var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()").Select(node => node.InnerText);
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in text)
{
   output.AppendLine(line);
}
string textOnly = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(output.ToString());
```

**3**

```
string html;
// obtain some arbitrary html....
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    html = client.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104");
}
// use the html agility pack: http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlTextNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")) {
    sb.AppendLine(node.Text);
}
string final = sb.ToString();
```

Obs. a primeira opção tem um gap com CDATA, se não for o caso, pode utilizá-la, caso contrário utilize a segunda.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags